# Pause Background Music from ViewController to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have backgroundmusic, declared in my app delegate for all my viewcontrollers.

appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{

AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}
```

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSString *backgroundMusicString =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"backgroundmusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicString] error:nil];
backgroundMusic.delegate=self;
backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops=-1;
backgroundMusic.volume=0.2;
[backgroundMusic play];

return YES;
}
```

works fine. But how can i pause my background music in a viewcontroller? 
i have a button to toggle it on off, but [backgroundMusic pause]; doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)backgroundMusicOnOff:(id)sender {

}
```

Comment: Show the code you use to pause the music.

Comment: i haven't any code to pause the music. the code should for my button but [backgroundMusic pause]; doesn't work. i don't know why my audio player in the  appdelegate isn't visible for my view controller...

Comment: The code to pause the music needs to be in your app delegate. Then you call that app delegate method from the view controller.

Comment: you mean that i need a method that stops playing the background music in appdelegate and then calling from view controller? but how can i call it from there?